# Как коротко записать массив символов на python?

Tags: python

Как записать массив строк содержащий целые числа от 1 до 100
`mas=['1','2','3',...,'100']`
И как по нему осуществлять переход

Comment: а зачем вам массив строк? сделайте массив чисел, все будет автоматически приводиться к строке, когда это будет нужно:
`for i in range(1,101):
     mas[i] = i `

Comment: просто я хочу использовать для записи измененных мною изображений с помощью
filename='img'+число из массива+'.jpg'
imwrite(filename)
и когда я делаю как вы предложили выдает ошибку о том что строка не складывается с int

Comment: делайте так: `filename = 'img' + str(число из массива) + '.jpg' `

Comment: Классический пример проблемы XY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать циклом:

```py
mas = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    mas.append(str(i))
```

Можно использовать list comprehension:

```py
mas = [str(i) for i in range(101)]
```

Можно воспользоваться функциональным программированием:

```py
mas = list(map(str, range(1, 101)))
```